# Browser file download not working for a file stored on server

Tags: file, spring-mvc, browser, controller, force-download

I have a file  on server which is to be downloaded using the browser download. No error  is being thrown but no download window appears for the file download.
Please help.

My controller code is:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public void downloadFile(
        @ModelAttribute("path") final String path, HttpServletRequest  request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try {

        logger.error("inside download get try");    
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        File downloadFile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);
        // get MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(path);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
            mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
        // set headers for the response
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        // get output stream of the response
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outStream.close();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("inside download get catch");          
        throw new IndiciumException("Can't download the audit file");
    }
```

My response in the firebug is like:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
5 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 502>>stream
x��T]o�0}�W���!��?��F�eʤ�k���4x]�����ʿ�
Nł��Ea||���^�Mt�cHi��PpBc��m��F�#
��h�?N����a~��3��=,r}�_����J8M��*u��[q(q�$U)�?��|o�:�|     
�P�T�
/�Ƭ���|��m��~\_��X�*���m98 s��_��+�c��ut�77��v��ݻ��(M       
�V�K���@�m�w��=�HS����(Х-�8���ն
ܮJ�g��a1������M�Ƿ��3E��&Ǧ!��$a|ܩ�вb���$цT�kSׁ8�m�>��
�0E(����|�BJb �?����f2.3�8�'�sbϰLި�O9ˎ�    
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Contents 5 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC    
/ImageI]/Font<</F1 1 0 R
/F2 2 0 R/F3 3 0 R/F4 4 0 R>>>>/Parent 6 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Times-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Times-Italic/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Times-Roman/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Kids[7 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 1/ITXT(5.0.6)>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 6 0 R>>
endobj
9 0 obj        
1T3XT BVBA)>>
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000768 00000 n 
0000000857 00000 n 
trailer
<</Info 9 0 R/ID [<1b6717a8f36527b1db89d35fc22e9da5>     
<c2e3cf9ec60f1d29ea766dc>]/Root 8 0 R/Size
10>>
startxref
1364
%%EOF
```

And the response header is:

```
Cache-Control   
must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0


Content-Disposition 
attachment; filename = exportpdf1432033492.pdf


Content-Type    
application/pdf


Date    
Tue, 19 May 2015 11:04:52 GMT


Expires 
0


Pragma  
no-cache


Server  
Apache-Coyote/1.1


Transfer-Encoding   
chunked


X-Frame-Options 
DENY


X-XSS-Protection    
1; mode=block


x-content-type-options  
nosniff
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the server-side code in a debugger? What does the browser's network traffic show? What type/headers/payload does the response have?

Comment: The response header and the response is same as expected with in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

It seems your code is writing properly to response's output stream so maybe you just need to call **flush()** on it when your done writing. I was in a similar situation some time ago.

Comment: I did but it is still not working :( someone please help...it doesn't throw any error even to debug :'-(

Comment: You can check the following points:

1. if anything at all gets written to the output stream;

2. what happens if you don't close the output stream, you shouldn't do it anyway;

Comment: Hi, The output stream has got data as expected and if I don't close the output stream, nothing happens but it behaves in the same way. Am still struggling :( Thanks anyway for you reply.

Comment: After all the research I find that my code is correct and there is something wrong with spring configuration or I am missing some .jar. Someone please help what it could be?